# PHP upload the file using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I would like to upload a html file wherein multiple image exist in local as i upload the file after uploading all values which is in html came up into my screen display the same, using php is it possible an early reply will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work for you.

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTMLFile("youfilename.html");

echo $doc->saveHTML();